# Populating cells in a table with data from a page using an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show the variables that have been selected and generated on a page in a table under it at the click of a go button so the user can track their progress and download the resultant images that are provided from it, however I am at the very limit of my knowledge of javascript to do this.

the code I have so far is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //init data
  var arrayList = [{
      "Id": 0,
      "Name": "Select a target...",
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "M15",
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "M27"

    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "NGC891"
    }

  ];


  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayList.length; i++) {
    $('#choices').append('<option value="' + arrayList[i].Id + '">' + arrayList[i].Name + '</option>');
  }


});

$("#choices").change(function() {
  // $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
  //use this if using external json sets

  var $selection = $("#choices option:selected");
  var key = $selection.val();

  var vals = [];

  $(".imghere").attr("src", "");

switch (key) {
    case '1':
      text: ["Please Select a Filter","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"],
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red", "Green", "Blue"]; 
      $('#right').val('21:29:58.33');
      $('#desc').val('+12:10:01.2');
      break;
    case '2':
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"];
      $('#right').val('19:59:36.34');
      $('#desc').val('+22:43:16.09');
      break;
    case '3':
      vals = ["Please Select a Filter...","Red (Rp)", "Green (V)", "Blue (B)"];
      $('#right').val('02:22:33.4');
      $('#desc').val('+42:20:57.0');
      break;
    case '0':
      vals = ['Please Select a Filter...'];
  }
  
  

  var $secondChoice = $("#filter");
  $secondChoice.empty();
  $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
    $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });

});


$("#filter").change(function() {
  var $filter = $("#filter option:selected").val();
  var baseurl = "https://github.com/brychanjames/RTI-Simulator/blob/master/";
  var $showimg = baseurl + $filter + ".jpg";
  //$(".imghere").attr("src",$showimg); use this, the next line is demo purposes
  $(".imghere").attr("src", $showimg); /*use variable in place of the placeholder image*/


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<div class="form-group"><div class="row"><div class="col"><label for="target-list">Target Name:</label></div></div> 

<select id="choices" type="select" name="name" placeholder="Target Name" class="button form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></select>

<div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div></div> 
<div class="form-group">
<label>Right Ascension:</label> <input id="right" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ra" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div></div> <div class="form-group"><label>Declination:</label> <input id="desc" type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="dec" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div></div>

  <div><label class="wrapper" for="states">Filter</label>
<select id="filter" type="select" name="name" placeholder="Target Name" class="button form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

      </select>


  
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
              Go!
            </button></div> <div role="alert" class="alert alert-danger mt-3 invisible">

            
<table id="session-table"><thead><tr><th>Target Name</th> <th>Right Ascension</th> <th>Declination</th> <th>Exposure Time (sec)</th> <th>Filter</th> <th>Timestamp (UTC)</th> <th>Image type</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr></thead> 
 <tbody> <tr>   
      <td><input id="choices" type="text" placeholder="Target Name" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input id="right" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ra" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input id="desc" type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="dec" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>

      <td><input id="Exp" type="text" placeholder="N/A" name="Exp" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="filter" type="select" name="name" placeholder="Filter" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" id="datetime"></td>

      <td><input type="text" placeholder="JPEG" id="imageType"></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
      <td><input id="choices" type="text" placeholder="Target Name" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input id="right" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ra" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input id="desc" type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="dec" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>

      <td><input id="Exp" type="text" placeholder="N/A" name="Exp" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="filter" type="select" name="name" placeholder="Filter" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" id="datetime"></td>

      <td><input type="text" placeholder="JPEG" id="imageType"></td>
</tr>
<tr>   
      <td><input id="choices" type="text" placeholder="Target Name" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input id="right" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ra" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input id="desc" type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="dec" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>

      <td><input id="Exp" type="text" placeholder="N/A" name="Exp" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="filter" type="select" name="name" placeholder="Filter" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" id="datetime"></td>

      <td><input type="text" placeholder="JPEG" id="imageType"></td>
</tr>
    
</tbody></table></div>
```

I want to show the Target name and Filter that has been selected, the RA and Dec of the Target, and the date/time each time the go button has been selected, how do I do that?

Comment: You've said what you want, but what is your exact question?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I forgot to ask a question, my brains a bit addled from today, I have edited the text accordingly. I want to learn how to have those table cells populate as accordingly, as I currently do not know the right terms to use within the code.

Comment: id values have to be unique, so you can't reuse `choices` for every 'row'. If you then put all your options and such inside the arrayList as well, you can remove like half your code because you can just use the id of each element inside arrayData to immediately select the correct row instead of looping and then using a case to know what to do. Getting the target name is then just a `.filter()` on arrayData to find the data corresponding to the row id. "Smart data structures and dumb code work alot better than the other way around."

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, do you have any recommended reading that I could use to learn more?

Comment: I'll try writing an answer.

Comment: So, Stack Overflow isn't really the correct place for this type of inquiry. We answer **specific** questions about programming. Your question really is about learning the various skills and techniques needed to solve a particular use case that you have. Your best bet is Google, the Mozilla Developer Network, and the many tutorial type resources on the Internet. Because your scenario can be addressed in multiple ways, your question is likely to be closed as too broad or primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Shilly That would be most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all the relevant information about the spheres into the arrayList, the pattern to render, add events and change the visuals mostly stays the same:

You create some HTML using the correct sphere object from the array.
And then you append this in the correct place. If you put the click and change events in an easy place, you do not have to change or re-add them later.

Considering the events, the structure is also mostly the same: you get the id of the corresponding item inside the array so you can use that item to do the next step. This makes the info we have to get back from the HTML minimal, which in turn means we do not have to change the HTML if we add more spheres. If we would use the case syntax you had originally, you would have to change that case every time you would add another sphere.

I'll leave the styling, the full table structure and adding more error handlers to you. A lot can be made more efficient, you could like save all the selectors, so you do not have to query them from the DOM every time. Or use a state object to hold info like the currently selected filter. But I wanted to show the basics here.

```js
const celestial_spheres = [
  {
    "id": 134578521,
    "name": "M15",
    "ascention": "21:29:58.33",
    "declination": "+12:10:01.2",
    "filters": [
      { "name": "red", "values": [ 1, 2, 3  ] },
      { "name": "green", "values": [ 4, 5, 6 ] },
      { "name": "blue", "values": [ 7, 8, 9 ] }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 21412155,
    "name": "M27",
    "ascention": "19:59:36.34",
    "declination": "+22:43:16.09",
    "filters": [
      { "name": "red", "values": [ 10, 11, 12 ] },
      { "name": "green", "values": [ 13, 14, 15 ] },
      { "name": "blue", "values": [ 16, 17, 18 ] }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 452456321347564364,
    "name": "NGC891",
    "ascention": "02:22:33.4",
    "declination": "+42:20:57.0",
    "filters": [
      { "name": "red", "values": [ 19, 20, 21 ] },
      { "name": "green", "values": [ 22, 23, 24 ] },
      { "name": "blue", "values": [ 25, 26, 27 ] }
    ]
  }
];

const sphere_options = spheres => spheres.map( sphere => `<option value="${ sphere.id }">${ sphere.name }</option>` ).join( '' );
const filter_options = filters => filters.map( filter => `<option value="${ filter.name }">${ filter.name }</option>` ).join( '' );
const sphere_filter_row = ( id, filter ) => {
  const cells = filter.values.map( value => `<td>${ value }</td>` ).join( '' );
  return `<tr id="sphere_${ id }" data-type="${ filter.name }">${ cells}</tr>`;
};

const select_sphere = event => {
  const sphere_id = parseInt( event.target.value, 10 );
  const sphere = celestial_spheres.find( sphere => sphere.id === sphere_id );
  if ( !sphere ) throw new Error( `application.select_sphere - cannot find the sphere with id ${ sphere_id }` );
  else {
    const filter_selection = document.querySelector( '#sphere_filters' );
    const filters = filter_options( sphere.filters );
    filter_selection.innerHTML = `<option value="default">Please select a filter...</option>${ filters }`;
    const header = document.querySelector( '#sphere_name' );
    header.innerHTML = sphere.name;
    const ascention = document.querySelector( '#right_ascention' );
    ascention.innerText = sphere.ascention;
    const declination = document.querySelector( '#declination' );
    declination.innerText = sphere.declination;
    const sphere_rows = document.querySelector( '#sphere_rows' );
    sphere_rows.innerHTML = '';
  }
};

const select_filter = event => {
  const sphere_id = parseInt( document.querySelector( '#celestial_spheres' ).value, 10 );
  const sphere = celestial_spheres.find( sphere => sphere.id === sphere_id );
  const filter_name = event.target.value;
  const filter = sphere.filters.find( filter => filter.name === filter_name );
  const row = sphere_filter_row( sphere_id, filter );
  const sphere_rows = document.querySelector( '#sphere_rows' );
  sphere_rows.innerHTML = row;
};

const show_detail = event => {
  const row = event.target.closest( 'tr' );
  const sphere_id = parseInt( row.getAttribute( 'id' ).slice( 7 ), 10 );
  const sphere = celestial_spheres.find( sphere => sphere.id === sphere_id );
  alert( `You clicked the value "${ event.target.innerText }" of sphere "${ sphere_id }".` );
  // Do stuff with the clicked cell
};

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const sphere_selection = document.querySelector( '#celestial_spheres' );
  sphere_selection.innerHTML += sphere_options( celestial_spheres );
  sphere_selection.addEventListener( 'change', select_sphere );
  const filter_selection = document.querySelector( '#sphere_filters' );
  filter_selection.addEventListener( 'change', select_filter );
  const sphere_rows = document.querySelector( '#sphere_rows' );
  sphere_rows.addEventListener( 'click', show_detail );
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<select id="celestial_spheres">
  <option value="default">Select a target...</option>
</select>
<label >Right Ascention:</label>
<span id="right_ascention"></span>
<label >Declinaton:</label>
<span id="declination"></span>
<select id="sphere_filters"></select>
<table id="filter_details">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="sphere_name"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="sphere_rows"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, especially for taking the time to explain it as well as you did, that means a lot to me!

Comment: Hi @Shilly, thanks again for your help here, I was hoping you could help me with one last thing on this. I have been trying since Friday to use state objects to populate and hold the information in each row for each filter at the click of the go button and I am failing dismally. Can you show me how it is done please?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or something containing the current code so I can see what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Thanks for  taking a look @shilly heres a codepen of the current code https://codepen.io/brychan-govier/pen/xeGqZg

Comment: Exactly what information should appear in the table? I don't really understand, since after you select a sphere and a filter, I would expect to only have one row in the table until I select a different filter or sphere.

Comment: The information it currently populates with is correct. What I am trying to do is save the row that is first generated so that students can see a record of multiple different selections, for instance each colour filter the telescopes use, or different astronomical objects, eg.


Target Name Right Ascension Declination Exposure Time (sec) Filter Timestamp (UTC) Image type  
M15 21:29:58.33 +12:10:01.2 N/A Red (R) 
JPEG

Target Name Right Ascension Declination Exposure Time (sec) Filter Timestamp (UTC) Image type  
M15 21:29:58.33 +12:10:01.2 N/A Green (V) 
JPEG

etc

Comment: @BJG So basically every time time someone selects a sphere and filter, all that info should be added to the table instead of it overwriting the first row every time? Correct? If so, change `sphere_rows.innerHTML = row;` into `sphere_rows.innerHTML += row;`.

Comment: @BJG And if the row should only be added when 'go' is clicked instead of when the filter changes, just remove the onchange event from the filter and add the same function as a onclick event to the button instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: I have been trying to make the go button work on and off for months now and I'm sorry to say I really haven't quite understood your instructions on how to move the function from sphere_filters to a new function are you able to expand on your instruction some more please?

Comment: Do you mean changing `const filter_selection = document.querySelector( '#sphere_filters' ); filter_selection.addEventListener( 'change', select_filter );` into `<button id="button_go">Go</button>` and `const button_go = document.querySelector( '#button_go' ); button_go.addEventListener( 'click', select_filter );` ?

Comment: Yes, I had tried something similar, but had a syntactic error compared to what you've just provided, I still cannot get it to work though, I've put the whole code into a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/brychang/gzmdt81s/22/ to provide wider context. Is something else I've done interfering with the javascript?

Comment: I'll have a look in 15mins or so.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm limited to 30k characters inside a snippet body, I have to make a new answer to be able to include the code.
I had to strip all the styling and the modal that isn't visible to be able to post a working example.

Instead of the `onchange` event on filter_selection, we want a click event on the 'go' button.
So I created a different function, `show_sphere()`.

At the moment we just log everything that is selected to the console. I *guess* you'll want to change the `sphere_filter_row()` function as well to match the new format of your table, but I wasn't sure, so I did not include it yet.

```js
var span = document.getElementById('current');

function time() {
  var d = new Date();
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var t = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var x = d.getDate();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  t = checkTime(t);
  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  x = checkTime(x);
  span.textContent = y + "-" + t + "-" + x + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
setInterval(time, 1000);


function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

const celestial_spheres = [{
    "id": 134578521,
    "name": "M15",
    "right_ascension": "21:29:58.33",
    "declination": "+12:10:01.2",
    "filters": [{
        "name": "Red (R)",
        "values": ['M15', "21:29:58.33", "+12:10:01.2", 'N/A', 'Red (R)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/M15-Red.jpeg" target="_blank">M15 Red (R)</a>']
      },
      {
        "name": "Green (V)",
        "values": ['M15', "21:29:58.33", "+12:10:01.2", 'N/A', 'Green (V)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/M15-Green.jpeg" target="_blank">M15 Green (V)</a>']
      },
      {
        "name": "Blue (B)",
        "values": ['M15', "21:29:58.33", "+12:10:01.2", 'N/A', 'Blue (B)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/M15-Blue.jpeg" target="_blank">M15 Blue (B)</a>']
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 21412155,
    "name": "M27",
    "right_ascension": "19:59:36.34",
    "declination": "+22:43:16.09",
    "filters": [{
        "name": "Red (R)",
        "values": ['M27', "19:59:36.34", "+22:43:16.09", 'N/A', 'Red (R)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/M27-Red.jpeg" target="_blank">M27 Red (R)</a>']
      },
      {
        "name": "Green (V)",
        "values": ['M27', "19:59:36.34", "+22:43:16.09", 'N/A', 'Green (V)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/M27-Green.jpeg" target="_blank">M27 Green (V)</a>']
      },
      {
        "name": "Blue (B)",
        "values": ['M27', "19:59:36.34", "+22:43:16.09", 'N/A', 'Blue (B)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/M27-Blue.jpeg" target="_blank">M27 Blue (B)</a>']
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 452456321347564364,
    "name": "NGC891",
    "right_ascension": "02:22:33.4",
    "ra": "02:22:33.4",
    "declination": "+42:20:57.0",
    "dec": "+42:20:57.0",
    "filters": [{
        "name": "Red (R)",
        "values": ['NGC891', "02:22:33.4", "+42:20:57.0", 'N/A', 'Red (R)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/NGC891-Red.jpeg" target="_blank">NGC891 Red (R)</a>']
      },
      {
        "name": "Green (V)",
        "values": ['NGC891', "02:22:33.4", "+42:20:57.0", 'N/A', 'Green (V)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/NGC891-Green.jpeg" target="_blank">NGC891 Green (V) (R)</a>']
      },
      {
        "name": "Blue (B)",
        "values": ['NGC891', "02:22:33.4", "+42:20:57.0", 'N/A', 'Blue (B)', '<p id="datetime">', '<a href="//www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/NGC891-Blue.jpeg" target="_blank">NGC891 Blue (B)</a>']
      }
    ]
  }
];

const sphere_options = spheres => spheres.map(sphere => `<option value="${ sphere.id }">${ sphere.name }</option>`).join('');

const filter_options = filters => filters.map(filter => `<option value="${ filter.name }">${ filter.name }</option>`).join('');

/* REMOVE THIS
const sphere_filter_row = (id, filter) => {
  const cells = filter.values.map(value => `<td>${ value }</td>`).join('');
  return `<tr id="sphere_${ id }" data-type="${ filter.name }">${ cells}</tr>`;
};
*/
const sphere_filter_row = sphere => {
 return [
  `<tr id="sphere_${ sphere.id }">`,
   `<td>${ sphere.name }</td>`,
   `<td>${ sphere.ascension }</td>`,
   `<td>${ sphere.declination }</td>`,
   `<td>${ sphere.exposure }</td>`,
   `<td>${ sphere.filter }</td>`,
   `<td>${ new Date().toJSON() }</td>`,
   `<td>${ sphere.image }</td>`,
   '<td></td>',
   '<td></td>',
  '</tr>'
 ].join( '' );
};

const select_filter = event => {
  const sphere_id = parseInt(document.querySelector('#celestial_spheres').value, 10);
  const sphere = celestial_spheres.find(sphere => sphere.id === sphere_id);
  const filter_name = event.target.value;
  const filter = sphere.filters.find(filter => filter.name === filter_name);
  const row = sphere_filter_row(sphere_id, filter);
  const sphere_rows = document.querySelector('#sphere_rows');
  sphere_rows.innerHTML += row;
};

const show_sphere = () => {
  const sphere_id = parseInt( document.querySelector('#celestial_spheres').value, 10 );
  const sphere = celestial_spheres.find(sphere => sphere.id === sphere_id);
  if (!sphere) throw new Error(`application.select_sphere - cannot find the sphere with id ${ sphere_id }`);
  else {
    const filter_name = document.querySelector('#sphere_filters').value;
    const filter = sphere.filters.find(filter => filter.name === filter_name);
    const exposure = document.querySelector('#exposure-time-input').value;
    /* ADD THIS */
    const row = sphere_filter_row({
      id: sphere.id,
      name: sphere.name,
      ascension: sphere.right_ascension,
      declination: sphere.declination,
      exposure,
      filter: filter.name,
      image: filter.values[ 6 ]
    });
    document.querySelector( '#session-table tbody' ).innerHTML += row;
  }
};

const select_sphere = event => {
  const sphere_id = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
  const sphere = celestial_spheres.find(sphere => sphere.id === sphere_id);
  if (!sphere) throw new Error(`application.select_sphere - cannot find the sphere with id ${ sphere_id }`);
  else {
    const filter_selection = document.querySelector('#sphere_filters');
    const filters = filter_options(sphere.filters);
    filter_selection.innerHTML = `<option value="default">Please select a filter...</option>${ filters }`;
    // const header = document.querySelector( '#sphere_name' );
    //  header.innerHTML = sphere.name;
    const ascension = document.getElementById('right_ascension_input');
    ascension.value = sphere.right_ascension;
    const declination = document.getElementById('declination_input');
    declination.value = sphere.declination;
    /* REMOVE THIS
    const sphere_rows = document.querySelector('#sphere_rows');
    sphere_rows.innerHTML = '';
    */
  }
};

const show_detail = event => {
  const row = event.target.closest('tr');
  const sphere_id = parseInt(row.getAttribute('id').slice(7), 10);
  const sphere = celestial_spheres.find(sphere => sphere.id === sphere_id);
  alert(`You clicked the value "${ event.target.innerText }" of sphere "${ sphere_id }".`);
  // Do stuff with the clicked cell
};


const sphere_selection = document.querySelector('#celestial_spheres');
sphere_selection.innerHTML += sphere_options(celestial_spheres);
sphere_selection.addEventListener('change', select_sphere);

const button_go = document.querySelector('#button_go');
button_go.addEventListener('click', show_sphere );

/* REMOVE OR FIX THIS
const sphere_rows = document.querySelector('#sphere_rows');
sphere_rows.addEventListener('click', show_detail);
*/
```

```html
<div id="app"><a href="https://rti.lco.global/generate_token" class=""></a> <a href="https://rti.lco.global/" class="router-link-active"></a> <a href="https://rti.lco.global/rti" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active"></a>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row pt-2 pb-2 pl-5 pr-5">
              <div class="col-auto mr-auto">
                <div class="navbar-header"><a href="https://lco.global/" title="LCO.global" rel="home" class="navbar-brand"><img id="lco-logo" src="http://www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/LCO-logo-web.jpg" alt="Las Cumbres Observatory" float:left></a> <a id="lco-name" class="navbar-brand">Real-Time Interface <font color=red><strong> Simulator</strong></font color>
                  </a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto"><span>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong>Current Time: &nbsp;</strong></td>
                      <td><span id="current"><span class="fixed-width-time"></span></span></td>
                      <td>
                        UTC
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong>Session start: &nbsp;</strong></td>
                      <td><span id="datetime"><span class="fixed-width-time"></span>
                          <script>
                            var dt = new Date();
                            document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML =
                              (dt.getFullYear()) + "-" +
                              (("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) + "-" +
                              (("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) + " " +
                              (("0" + dt.getHours()).slice(-2)) + ":" +
                              (("0" + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2)) + ":" + (("0" + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2));

                          </script>
                        </span></td>
                      <td>
                        UTC
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><strong>Session end: &nbsp;</strong></td>
                      <td><span class="fixed-width-time">2019-00-00 00:00:00</span></td>
                      <td>
                        UTC
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid intro downPage blue">
            <div class="row pt-2 pb-2 pl-5 pr-5">
              <div class="col"><span class="welcome-text welcome-text-big">WELCOME TO THE RTI SIMULATOR</span></div>
              <div class="col right-aligned"><span><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#status-info-modal" href="https://rti.lco.global/rti" class="link-text pl-4">Status info</a></span><span><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#help-modal" href="https://rti.lco.global/rti" class="link-text pl-4">Help</a></span><span><a href="https://rti.lco.global/" class="link-text pl-4 router-link-active">Exit session</a></span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <!---->
              <!---->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div id="status-container" class="row light-border p-2">
                <div class="col-5 ml-3">
                  <div id="image-display">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col"><img src="http://www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/lastsnap.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 500px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pt-1">
                      <div class="col">Current sky</div>
                      <div class="col-auto"><a href="https://rti.lco.global/rti#" onclick="return false;" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="" data-content="Image of the sky at the current site. Contains a timestamp of when it was taken in the top left
      corner. The image is usually updated about every 4 minutes. However, sometimes images are not regularly updated
      due to network issues." data-original-title="Info">Info</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col-6 ml-auto mr-3">
                  <div class="row pb-1">
                    <div class="col"><strong>You are logged in to observe on the Australia 2-meter telescope</strong></div>
                  </div>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><strong class="session-status" title="Your text here">Session:</strong> <span class="session-status">&nbsp; In progress &nbsp;</span>
                    <!---->
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><strong class="session-status" title="Your text here">Observatory:</strong> <span class="session-status" title="Your text here">&nbsp; Available &nbsp;</span>
                    <!---->
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><strong class="session-status" title="Your text here">Telescope:</strong> <span class="session-status" title="Your text here">&nbsp; Operating &nbsp;</span>
                    <!---->
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><strong class="session-status" title="Your text here">Camera:</strong> <span class="session-status" title="Your text here">&nbsp; Idle &nbsp;</span>
                    <!---->
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><strong class="session-status" title="Your text here">Progress:</strong> <span class="session-status" title="Your text here">&nbsp; Ready &nbsp;</span>
                    <!---->
                  </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="pt-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-6 mt-auto mb-auto">
                    <div>
                      <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="radio radio-inline"><label><strong>Target Input Mode:</strong></label><label><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="optionsRadios2" value="Manual" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Unavailable in Simulator mode" onclick="this.checked=false;
alert('Unavailable in Simulator mode')">Manual</label><label><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="optionsRadios2" value="list" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Select the celestial object you wish to see" onmouseover="('Select select from a list of celestial objects')" checked>List</label></div>
                        </div>
                        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col"><label for="target-list" title="Select the celestial opject you wish to see">Target Name:</label></div>
                          </div>
                          <select id="celestial_spheres" type="select" name="name" class="button form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                            <option value="default">Select a Target...</option>
                          </select>
                          <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"><label title="The distance of a point east of the First Point of Aries, measured along the celestial equator and expressed in hours, minutes, and seconds.">Right Ascension:</label>
                          <span id="right_ascension"></span>
                          <input id="right_ascension_input" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS.S" name="ascension" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                          <div class="form-group"><label title="The angular distance of a point north or south of the celestial equator">Declination:</label>
                            <span id="declination"></span>
                            <input id="declination_input" type="text" placeholder="DD:MM:SS.S" name="#declination" id="#declination" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div><label class="wrapper" for="states" title="Select whether you'd like to use the Red, Blue or Green filter for your image">Filter</label>
                          <select id="sphere_filters" type="select" name="name" placeholder="Target Name..." class="button form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                            <option value="default">Select a Filter...</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group"> </div>
                        <div class="form-group"><label title="How long would you like the camera to image the object, disabled in simulation mode">Exposure Time:</label> <input name="exposureSeconds" type="number" id="exposure-time-input" placeholder="N/A" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                          <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                      <div class="total-time-text">&nbsp;</div>
                      <div data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-placement="right" class="tooltip-wrapper ">

                        <button id="button_go" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Go!</button></div>
                      <div role="alert" class="alert alert-danger mt-3 invisible">

                        (<a href="https://rti.lco.global/rti#" onclick="return false;" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="" data-content="A target may not be visible because it is too close to the moon, if it is below the
      horizon, or if it is too low on the horizon for the telescope to point at." data-original-title="Info">Info</a>)
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-auto ml-auto">
                    <div id="imagehere" class="pb-3">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><img src="http://www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/loading.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 500px;"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row pt-1">
                        <div class="col">Live webcam</div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                          <!---->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="imagehere">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><img src="http://www.faulkes-telescope.com/wp-content/uploads/noImageAvailableYet.jpg" class="imghere" style="width: 500px;"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row pt-1">
                        <div class="col">Most recent image</div>
                        <div class="col-auto"><a href="https://rti.lco.global/rti#" onclick="return false;" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="" data-content="This is a thumbnail of the most recent image taken. Note that the image shown here at first
      may be left over from a previous session." data-original-title="Info">Info</a></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="help-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="help-modal-title" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
            <div role="dialog" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 id="help-modal-title" class="modal-title">Help</h5> <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="status-info-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="status-info-modal-title" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
            <div role="dialog" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 id="status-info-modal-title" class="modal-title">Status info</h5> <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div>
                    <p class="h4">Session status</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                      <li><strong>Not yet started</strong>
                        The session has not yet started.
                      </li>
                      <li><strong>Ended</strong>
                        The session has ended.
                      </li>
                      <li><strong>In progress</strong>
                        The session is currently under way.
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    </p>
                    <p class="h4">Observatory status</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                      <li><strong>Sun-up</strong>
                        Sun-up The telescope cannot be used because there is a risk of sunlight hitting the optics.
                      </li>
                      <li><strong>Closed for bad weather</strong>
                        The telescope cannot be used because weather conditions preclude observing. These might be conditions
                        which could damage the telescope (e.g. rain or high winds) or conditions that could inhibit observations
                        such as thick cloud layers.
                      </li>
                      <li><strong>Closed for maintenance</strong>
                        The telescope has been disabled or switched to manual for essential engineering activity.
                      </li>
                      <li><strong>Closed for technical failure</strong>
                        A technical failure is preventing observing. The failure modes currently captured are:
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            an essential service required for observing is not available, e.g. the camera or focus
                          </li>
                          <li>a power fault has been detected, e.g. running on batteries due to power outage</li>
                          <li>
                            the telescope is currently performing a house-keeping task, e.g. opening and focusing after a period
                            of bad weather
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            the hardware system suffered a failure
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            the software system suffered a failure
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    </p>
                    <p class="h4">Camera status</p>
                    <p><strong>Failed</strong>
                      The camera or filter wheel suffered a hardware failure. They may recover automatically in a few minutes.
                    </p>
                    <p class="h4">Progress</p>
                    <p><strong>Error on last observation</strong>
                      The most recent observation ended in failure either due to a technical fault or because it was cancelled.
                      See the <span style="font-style: italic;">Observatory status</span> status for additional information on
                      faults.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-12"><br> <br>
            <div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <!---->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="table-caption mb-1">Session Images</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto"><a href="https://archive.lco.global/?PROPID=FTPEPO2017AB-002&amp;SITEID=coj&amp;TELID=0m4a&amp;start=2019-01-09%2010:15&amp;end=2019-01-09%2010:45" target="_blank">LCO Science Archive (this session's images)</a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto;">


                    <table id="session-table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Target Name</th>
                          <th>Right Ascension</th>
                          <th>Declination</th>
                          <th>Exposure Time (sec)</th>
                          <th>Filter</th>
                          <th>Timestamp (UTC)</th>
                          <th>Image type</th>
                          <th></th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <!-- REMOVE THIS
                        <tr>
                      <tbody id="sphere_rows"></tbody>
                      </tr>
                      -->
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="footer col-md-12">
            Copyright © 2018 Las Cumbres Observatory. All rights reserved.
            <br></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ahhh I didn't even think about doing it that way thank you, now how do I take the content from populating in the console to the table?

Comment: I think you mean adding a row to `<tbody id="sphere_rows"></tbody>` ? Same way as we did before, by using the `sphere_filter_row()`. function. We just have to update it to reflect the new format of the table.

Comment: 1) Change `<tbody><tr><tbody id="sphere_rows"></tbody></tr></tbody>` into `<tbody></tbody>`. There is not need for the inner table, that only complicates things. 2) Change the  `sphere_filter_row()` function to what's shown in the code. The table structure is different, so we need a different row. 3) Call sphere_filter_row() and append the result to the table as shown inside `show_sphere()`. So not much changes, just the way we construct the row to match the new table.

Comment: That has worked perfectly, you have been amazing, thank you for all your help!